# Resons for potentially bad performance of numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, tensorflow

I have been running into performance issues with numpy. I tested different ways to compute a dot product, but similar performance issues have been seen with other numpy functions.

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def np_dot(U, X):
    tic = timeit.default_timer()
    X_bar = np.dot(U.T, X)
    toc = timeit.default_timer()
    print("np.dot took {:.4f} s".format(toc-tic))
    return X_bar

def np_at(U, X):
    tic = timeit.default_timer()
    X_bar = U.T @ X
    toc = timeit.default_timer()
    print("np @ took {:.4f} s".format(toc-tic))
    return X_bar

def np_matmul(U, X):
    tic = timeit.default_timer()
    X_bar = np.matmul(U.T, X)
    toc = timeit.default_timer()
    print("np.matmul took {:.4f} s".format(toc-tic))
    return X_bar

def np_einsum(U, X):
    tic = timeit.default_timer()
    X_bar = np.einsum('ij,jk', U.T, X)
    toc = timeit.default_timer()
    print("np.einsum took {:.4f} s".format(toc-tic))
    return X_bar

def tf_matmul(U, X):
    tic = timeit.default_timer()
    X_bar = tf.matmul(U.T, X)
    toc = timeit.default_timer()
    print("tf.matmul took {:.4f} s".format(toc-tic))
    return X_bar


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("is_gpu_available?", tf.test.is_gpu_available(), tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
    print("numpy version:", np.__version__)
    print("tensorflow version:", tf.__version__)
    
    M = N = 1000
    X = np.random.rand(M, N)
    U = np.random.rand(M, N)
    X_bar = np_dot(U, X)
    X_bar0 = np_at(U, X)
    X_bar1 = np_matmul(U, X)
    X_bar2 = np_einsum(U, X)
    X_bar3 = tf_matmul(U, X)
    print(np.allclose(X_bar, X_bar0))
    print(np.allclose(X_bar, X_bar1))
    print(np.allclose(X_bar, X_bar2))
    print(np.allclose(X_bar, X_bar3))
```

The output on my laptop (with Windows 10 and python 3.8) is:

```
is_gpu_available? False False
numpy version: 1.19.2
tensorflow version: 2.2.0
np.dot took 12.5368 s
np @ took 14.3303 s
np.matmul took 14.0634 s
np.einsum took 0.5937 s
tf.matmul took 0.0263 s
True
True
True
True
```

meaning **the standard `@` is 545 times slower than than it could be!** On a friends laptop the result look more like expected (with Ubuntu and python 3.6.9):

```
is_gpu_available? False False
numpy version: 1.19.5
tensorflow version: 1.14.0
np.dot took 0.0192 s
np @ took 0.0196 s
np.matmul took 0.0208 s
np.einsum took 0.3893 s
tf.matmul took 0.0280 s
True
True
True
True
```

Interestingly, numpys `einsum` does not seem to be affected by whatever is going wrong on my laptop and neither is tensorflow.

What is going on here?
What are the potential reasons for such a huge performance difference?

**edit:**

Always make sure numpy is using some BLAS library. Read more about it here: [Boosting numpy: Why BLAS Matters](https://markus-beuckelmann.de/blog/boosting-numpy-blas.html).

In my case `numpy.show_config()` returns the following:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blas_opt_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_clapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
flame_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_3_10_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
atlas_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
lapack_opt_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]
```

Comment: what is the BAS/LAPACK that your numpy was built with? what does `numpy.show_config()` give you?

Comment: in short:
blas_mkl_info, blis_info, openblas_info, atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info, atlas_3_10_blas_info, atlas_blas_threads_info, atlas_blas_info, accelerate_info, blas_info, blas_src_info, blas_opt_info, lapack_mkl_info, openblas_lapack_info, openblas_clapack_info, flame_info, atlas_3_10_threads_info, atlas_3_10_info, atlas_threads_info, atlas_info, lapack_info, lapack_src_info, lapack_opt_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

Comment: You *really* should edit your quesiton and add that there...

Comment: It looks like your numpy installation *isn't using a BLAS or LAPACK library*. Which would definitely explain this performance issue

Comment: Thank you! I have been using ParaView Python, which somehow did not use BLAS. Other Python interpreter on my machine work just fine.